# Identity Server exception - Lifetime validation failed and Unable to decode the header 'System.String' as Base64Url encoded string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

When the token is expired or tampered token is passed to call an api in postman, I get exception as mentioned below. Now how to return this as proper response is my concern in asp.net core.

**Token expired:**

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenExpiredException: IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: 'System.DateTime', Current time: 'System.DateTime'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateLifetime(Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateLifetime(Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

**Token tampered and passed:**

```
System.ArgumentException: IDX12729: Unable to decode the header 'System.String' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.FormatException: IDX10400: Unable to decode: 'System.String' as Base64url encoded string.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(String str)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(String arg)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtHeader.Base64UrlDeserialize(String base64UrlEncodedJsonString)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken.Decode(String[] tokenParts, String rawData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken.Decode(String[] tokenParts, String rawData)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(String token)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

The above mentioned problems are handled after adding the following,
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUL44.png)

Now iam facing with new exception[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjpIz.png)

Comment: what is actually the question and can you tell me a bit more about what you try to do? What response do you want to have? that you can access the API? 

perhaps posta sample API configuration and a copy of your access token?

Comment: When i pass the token that is expired/tampered, I want to handle the above mentioned exceptions and return proper message as expired or token is tampered.

Comment: can you paste the code that shows how you are protecting your API? (your startup class) Using AddJwtBearer?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-install the Newtonsoft.Json library via `Nuget`. Or adding the Newtonsoft.Json dll to your project, it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The proper response from the API is to always return a 401 Unauthorized status code regardless if the token is expired or invalid/tampered. That is all that the client should care about.

Returning to detailed information about why it failed can actually help the attacker.